# I need file upload to networkless OS with IPMI

Tags: linux, nic, ipmi

Using an IPMI-mounted iso file, I've installed a simple Ubuntu remote server (no X, no Java, etc). However, the kernel has no driver for the NIC. So, after booting it, I am stuck. I've compiled the appropriate (and tested) kernel module, it locates on my local workstation.
Using the IPMI, can I upload it to the filesystem of the remote Linux? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since your machine already boots, you could write a new ISO file that contains your kernel module and remotely mount it.  It will appear as a CD inserted in the emulated drive.

Comment: Yes, this really is a good idea. I will create a customized CD if there won't be a direct method for the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ZModem](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/upload-zmodem.html) to transfer files.  Run `rz` on the receiving side and `sz` on the sending side.

Comment: Zmodem may be fine. Shall I create a special channel between the to OSs with the IPMI card?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Zmodem makes a data transfer stream on top of a shell session.